# Moving the hold button on Android phone app

Tags: android

Is there a way we can access the android phone app and move it's hold button to Right  down instead of left top currently? Basically is it a non-open source google app (I see contacts is one) or can we download the source and modify it?

Thanks for pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Phone application is part of the open source. It is located in packages/apps/Phone.

Note that whatever phone you are using may have changed it from the AOSP though, so whatever they might have added or fixed will be lost if you replace with your own version of the application. You should try it first with a different name / package.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu! Will check this up and post my findings.